# Doing something when a condition is met

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, event-detection

I am attempting to solve a set of coupled differential equations using ParametricDSolveValue. I want a point, where a condition is met, to be marked on the corresponding plot.

The condition I want the integration to stop at is when:

```
ROCHE[2000] >= papsis[t]
```

where

```
ROCHE[dens_] := (0.65*RSUN*PROPCONST*(MWD/(0.6*MSUN))^(1/3))/(dens/3000)^(1/3);
```

and

```
papsis[t_] := a[t]*(1 - e[t]);
```

The integration is as follows:
My code:

```
LSUN = 3.83*10^26; 
MSUN = 1.989*10^30; 
MWD = MSUN; 
year = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"]]; 
km = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1, "Kilometers"], 
     "Meters"]]; timelimit = 
   year*2*10^9; Myr = 1*10^6*year; 

PROPCONST = 1.27; 

c = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], 
     "Meters/second"]]; \[Rho] = 2000; 
MAST[rast_] := (4/3)*Pi*rast^3*\[Rho]; 
RSUN = 696340000; 
AU = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], 
     "meters"]]; 

L[t_] := (3.26*LSUN*(MWD/(0.6*MSUN)))/
    (0.1 + t/Myr)^1.18; 

dadt = (-(1/c^2))*((RAST^2*L[t]*
      (2 + 3*e[t]^2))/(4*MAST[RAST]*a[t]*
      (1 - e[t]^2)^(3/2))); 
dedt = (-(5/c^2))*((RAST^2*L[t]*e[t])/
     (8*MAST[RAST]*a[t]^2*
      Sqrt[1 - e[t]^2])); 

prsol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {Derivative[1][a][t] == dadt, 
    Derivative[1][e][t] == dedt, 
    a[0] == 2*AU, e[0] == 0.5}, {a, e}, 
   {t, 0, timelimit}, {RAST}]
```

Is there any way of doing this in Mathematica? Sorry, I'm very new to the language.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html). More specifically, you would want to build up something like: `WhenEvent[yourCondition, Sow[coordinatesOfThePoint]]`. You can then collect the sowed coordinates by wrapping the whole `ParametricNDSolve` in `Reap`. See [Collecting Expressions during Evaluation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html#8044).

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried that and keep getting the error "The function value is not true or false". Also, I;m not sure how to mark the resulting plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Evaluate`. Otherwise, because `WhenEvent` holds its argument (prevents them from evaluating; see `HoldAll`), it won't see the `a[t]` and `e[t]` in `papsis[t]`.  It has to replace the symbolic expressions `a[t]` and `e[t]` with their computed values, and they have to be present in the text of the condition for this to happen.

```
prsol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
   Derivative[1][a][t] == dadt,
   Derivative[1][e][t] == dedt,
   WhenEvent[Evaluate[ROCHE[2000] >= papsis[t]], "StopIntegration"],
   a[0] == 2*AU, e[0] == 0.5}, {a, e}, {t, 0, timelimit}, {RAST}]
```