# Dynamically generate system to use with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection, generalized-function

I have a d-dimensional differential equation that I want to solve that takes the following form:

When d = 1:

```
NDSolveValue[{
{v1'[t]}==V'[t],
WhenEvent[t>=T,{tStart=T,"StopIntegration"}],
WhenEvent[v1[t]>=thresholds[[1]],{tStart=t,spk={1,t,w},"StopIntegration"}],
WhenEvent[v1[t]<=-thresholds[[1]],{tStart=t,spk={1,t,-w},"StopIntegration"}],
{v1[tStart],}==V[tStart]
},{v1},{t,tStart,T}];
```

When d = 2:

```
NDSolveValue[{
{v1'[t],v2'[t]}==V'[t],
WhenEvent[t>=T,{tStart=T,"StopIntegration"}],
WhenEvent[v1[t]>=thresholds[[1]],{tStart=t,spk={1,t,w},"StopIntegration"}],
WhenEvent[v1[t]<=-thresholds[[1]],{tStart=t,spk={1,t,-w},"StopIntegration"}],
WhenEvent[v2[t]>=thresholds[[2]],{tStart=t,spk={2,t,w},"StopIntegration"}],
WhenEvent[v2[t]<=-thresholds[[2]],{tStart=t,spk={2,t,-w},"StopIntegration"}],
{v1[tStart],v2[tStart]}==V[tStart]
},{v1,v2},{t,tStart,T}];
```

But I want to generalize my code to handle any integer d ≥ 1 so that I'm not manually editing it every time I change d.

I attempted the following, which did not work:

```
    vList = Table[ToExpression["v" <> ToString[i]], {i, d}];
    system = Table[vList[[i]]'[t] == V'[t][[i]], {i, d}];
    events = Flatten@Table[
        {WhenEvent[vList[[i]][t] >= thresholds[[i]], {tStart = t, spk = {i, t, w}, "StopIntegration"}],
         WhenEvent[vList[[i]][t] <= -thresholds[[i]], {tStart = t, spk = {i, t, -w}, "StopIntegration"}]}, 
        {i, d}
    ];
 
        res = NDSolveValue[
            Join[
                system,
                {WhenEvent[t >= T, {tStart = T, "StopIntegration"}]},
                events,
                {Thread[Through[vList[tStart]] == V[tStart]]}
            ],
            vList,
            {t, tStart, T}
        ];
```

I think the events list is the current issue because it does not properly replace `i`:
`{WhenEvent[vList\[LeftDoubleBracket]i〛[t]>=thresholds\[LeftDoubleBracket]i〛,{tStart=t,spk={i,t,w},StopIntegration}],WhenEvent[vList\[LeftDoubleBracket]i〛[t]<=-thresholds\[LeftDoubleBracket]i〛,{tStart=t,spk={i,t,-w},StopIntegration}]}`

Any ideas?

Edit:
Based on Michael E2's comments below, here is the working code:
(It includes an outer loop that gives more context to what's going on.)

````
tStart=0;
spikes=Table[{i,tStart-eps,f[tStart-eps][[i]]},{i,d}];(*{{idx,time,weight}}*) 
V=buildV[spikes];

Until[tStart==T,
voltages=Array[v,d];
eqns={Table[v[i]'[t],{i,d}]==V'[t]};
initConds={Table[v[i][tStart],{i,d}]==V[tStart]};
events=Flatten@{
WhenEvent[t >= T, {tStart = T, "StopIntegration"}],
Table[With[{i=i,w=w,v=v[i][t],threshold=thresholds[[i]]},{
WhenEvent[v>=threshold,{tStart=t,spk={i,t,w}, "StopIntegration"}],
WhenEvent[v<=-threshold,{tStart=t,spk={i,t,-w}, "StopIntegration"}]
}],{i,d}]};
NDSolveValue[{eqns,initConds,events},voltages,{t,0,T}];
If[tStart<T,spikes=Join[spikes,{spk}]];
V=buildV[spikes];
];
```
````

Comment: (1) I'd probably use `vlist = Array[v, d]` and use the indexed variables. (2) You need to inject computed events into `WhenEvent` because it has the attribute `HoldAll`: `With[{evt = vList[[i]][t] >= thresholds[[i]]}, WhenEvent[evt, {tStart = t, spk = {i, t, w}, "StopIntegration"}]]`

Comment: Similar example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120379/4999 Alternative: Use `Evaluate`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235657/4999

Comment: Thanks, these comments are very helpful!  Just wondering, why do you recommend using `Array[v,d]` above in place of `Table`?  I looked up that `Array` doesn't have the `HoldAll` attribute like `Table`, but I don't understand the situations where I should prefer one or the other.  For example, in the similar example you linked, you used `Table` when creating `vars`.

Comment: `Table[v[k], {k, d}]` is fine, but requires more typing. I got used to `Table` years before `Array`. Sometimes old habits emerge. Since `v[..]` is used in `NDSolve`, `HoldAll` does not matter. `Table` needs `HoldAll` so that `k` can be localized before it is evaluated, just in case `k` has a global value. `Array` does not have that problem. `Array[f, d]` uses a function `f`. If you don't have a function, use `Table` instead. `Array` has extra forms that are sometimes convenient. `Table` has a more general iterator syntax. Otherwise, no big difference. Use whichever comes most naturally to you.

Comment: btw, my code is 50% slower using this approach. (Every time there is an event, I stop the NDSolve, recompile the system of equations, and then initialize a new NDSolve.  Thus, I am using this code in a loop, and the 50% slowdown is in comparison to when the system is manually written for a fixed `d` (as in the original post).  I am surprised... (I updated my post with my current code in case you have any thoughts.)  Thank you!

Comment: The slowdown actually scales with the number of interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

We need to assemble the different pieces of the NDSolveValue command separately:

First the When events:

```
when = Table[
    With[{vi = Symbol["v" <> ToString[i]], 
      ni = i}, {WhenEvent[
       vi[t] >= thresholds[[ni]], {tStart = t, spk = {ni, t, w}, 
        "StopIntegration"}], 
      WhenEvent[
       vi[t] <= -thresholds[[ni]], {tStart = t, spk = {ni, t, -w}, 
        "StopIntegration"}]}], {i, d}] // Flatten;
PrependTo[when, WhenEvent[t >= T, {tStart = T, "StopIntegration"}]];
```

Then the variables with different indices and arguments:

```
sym = Table[Symbol["v" <> ToString[i]], {i, d}];
symt = (#[t]) & /@ sym;
symst = (#[tStart]) & /@ sym;
```

Then the equations:

```
eq = {symt == V'[t], Sequence @@ when, symst == V[tStart]};
```

And finally the NDSolveValue command:

```
NDSolveValue[eq, sym, , {t, tStart, T}]

NDSolveValue[{{v1[t], v2[t]} == Derivative[1][V][t], 
  WhenEvent[t >= T, {tStart = T, "StopIntegration"}], 
  WhenEvent[v1[t] >= thresholds[[1]], {tStart = t, spk = {1, t, w}, 
    "StopIntegration"}], 
  WhenEvent[v1[t] <= -thresholds[[1]], {tStart = t, spk = {1, t, -w}, 
    "StopIntegration"}], 
  WhenEvent[v2[t] >= thresholds[[2]], {tStart = t, spk = {2, t, w}, 
    "StopIntegration"}], 
  WhenEvent[v2[t] <= -thresholds[[2]], {tStart = t, spk = {2, t, -w}, 
    "StopIntegration"}], 
{v1[tStart], v2[tStart]} == V[tStart]}, {v1,v2}, {t, tStart, T}]
```